# Problems with Passenger + Nginx: Failed to connect to a master node. Rails config error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

We're not sure if this is something not configured properly in our Rails setting, but we're seeing this error in our nginx error logs get repeated: Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Failed to connect to a master node at x.objectrocket.com:10804 ...

Here's a gist with more from the error log: https://gist.github.com/panabee/a291526f4dcf4cd434d9

How do we stop these errors?

We're on Rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means the ObjectRocket mongo server is refusing or timing out your connections. Contact them with the specific logs to work out why they refuse the connection.

Also, try setting your timeouts lower to avoid hanging connections for your clients:

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new(host, 27017, :connect_timeout => 1, :op_timeout => 1)
```

This [sets the connect and read timeouts](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/mongo_client.rb#L104). There's a :timeout option as well: it's related to connection pooling, not connecting to the server.

Neither :op_timeout nor :connect_timeout have a default value. Verify their settings by reading **MongoMapper.connection.connect_timeout**.

If you're using the 1.8.0 mongo gem version or later, you may want to replace the deprecated Mongo::Connection class with Mongo::MongoClient.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

In the first line of `environment.rb`.